# Images not generating in folders inside sites/default/files in drupal

Tags: image, drupal-7

I have placed the images in default/files folder but other images are not getting generated.The permissions of the files folder is also 777 but then also its not generating.I have clear the cache and checked the file system in configuration as well.

Can anyone please let me know what the reason could be for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GD toolkit was not installed, I installed it and it worked fine for me sudo apt-get install php5-gd